# Is Nextjs Link component SEO friendly without using anchor <a>?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have put up a small web app with next.js and would like to know from more experienced people if next.js Link component is SEO friendly (google knows how to crawl Link component) without using anchors  tags?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. behind the scenes, it will be the normal `<a>` tag.

```
<Link href="/about">
  <a>about</a>
</Link>
```

will be

```
 <a href="/about">about</a>
```

You can check in inspector.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. In my post I meant to ask only about the Link component without using anchor. Therefore, the question is if google knows how to follow <Link href="/about">about</Link>

Comment: If you use `<Link href="/about">about</Link>` it will be the same as normal link `<a href="/about">about</a>`

Comment: what about when using router.push ?

Comment: Having plain <Link href="/about">about</Link> was hurting my SEO and was being reported as having orphan pages. i.e. no page was linking to them despite using the plain Link tag only. The answer is correct, have an internal a tag, I'd advise not to use the plain "<Link href="/about">about</Link>"

Answer (score 1):

```
<Link href="/blah-blah" passHref>
  <a>Blah blah</a>
</Link>
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).